# finding the last coordinate of the triangle

Tags: typescript, trigonometry

There is a triangle.
Points are A, B and C.
Given all distances between them(AB, AC and BC) , the angle of B between A and C, and coordinates of point A and B, how can I find coordinate of C.

Below is my current code. It is working as expected in example case.

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

function calculatePointC(A: Point, B: Point, AB: number, angleABC: number, AC: number, BC: number): Point {
    // Convert angle from degrees to radians
    const angleRad = angleABC * (Math.PI / 180);

    // Calculate the vector from A to B
    const ABVector = { x: B.x - A.x, y: B.y - A.y };

    // Normalize the AB vector
    const ABLength = Math.sqrt(ABVector.x * ABVector.x + ABVector.y * ABVector.y);
    const normalizedAB = { x: ABVector.x / ABLength, y: ABVector.y / ABLength };

    // Calculate the coordinates of point C relative to point B
    const Cx_relB = AC * Math.cos(angleRad);
    const Cy_relB = AC * Math.sin(angleRad);

    // Convert relative coordinates to absolute coordinates
    const Cx = B.x + normalizedAB.x * Cx_relB - normalizedAB.y * BC;
    const Cy = B.y + normalizedAB.y * Cx_relB + normalizedAB.x * BC;

    return { x: Cx, y: Cy };
}
const pointA: Point = { x: 0, y: 0 };
const pointB: Point = { x: 4, y: 0 };
const distanceAB = 4;
const angleABC = 90; // in degrees
const distanceAC = 5;
const distanceBC = 3;

const pointC = calculatePointC(pointA, pointB, distanceAB, angleABC, distanceAC, distanceBC);
console.log("Coordinates of point C:", pointC);
```

But in the below case, the result is wrong.

```
const pointA: Point = { x: 0, y: 0 };
const pointB: Point = { x: 4, y: 0 };
const distanceAB = 4;
const angleABC = 36.87; // in degrees
const distanceAC = 3;
const distanceBC = 5;
```

the result should be { x: 0, y: 3 } but I am getting {x: 6.399996784445525,y: 5}.